# creating a restfull route for posting an answer in a quiz

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I'm working on a Course application. Each course has a chapter, and each chapter has a quiz.
For the quiz I want the user to post an answer on multiple choice questions (see screenshot)

[image]

However, I can't figure out right know to which controller action method I should post this form. The question is shown in the question#show action method, so should the user post the answer to the question to the question controller, but then which action? Or should he post it to the AnswersController? And if so to which action? It's a post, but he's not creating an action, right?

As you can see, I'm a bit puzzled about how to make the 'user answers question' scenario a restfull as possible.

My Question Model looks like this:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quiz
  has_many :answers, dependent: :delete_all
  validates_presence_of :title

  def self.subsequent_question(previous_question)
    where("id > ?", previous_question).first
  end

  def self.is_last?(question_id)
    question = Question.find(question_id)
    last_question = Question.last
    if question.id == last_question.id 
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

The QuestionsController:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    if Question.is_last?(params[:id])
      question = Question.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to quiz_complete_path(id: question.quiz_id) 
    else
      @question = Question.subsequent_question(params[:id])
      @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:quiz_id])
      @chapter = Chapter.find(@quiz.chapter_id)
      @course = Course.find(@chapter.course_id) 
    end
  end
end
```

The Answer model:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_uniqueness_of :is_correct, conditions: -> { where(is_correct: true) }
end
```

The AnswersController:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  def check_answer
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
    question = Question.find(@answer.question_id)
    if Question.is_last?(question.id)
      redirect_to quiz_complete_path(id: question.quiz_id)
    else
      next_question = Question.subsequent_question(question.id)
      redirect_to show_question_path(id: question.quiz_id, question_id: next_question.id)  
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: What font are you using for "Test Quiz 1"?

Comment: Can you post up some more code for us? Specifically, your controller which handles the "new" action, and your models for `question` and `answer` :)

Comment: Hi Rich, I'm using the Foundation framework, I believe they use the Helvetica Neue font-family.

Comment: I added the Question module and QuestionsController, and the Answer model and AnswersController code to my question

Comment: Nice - Apple uses Helvetica Neue in iOS7!